# How to decode curl output?

Tags: php, curl

Please help me to decode this below output, which I got when I run cURL.

Here is my code:

```
$headers = array(
            'Accept:application/json',
            'X-TB-PARTNER-AUTH: 45504852:abcdksalkrjwejkrjr'
        );


        $process = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.opentok.com/session/create");
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'p2p.preference=disabled');
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $server_output = curl_exec($process);
        print_r($server_output);
```

And my output is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2016 10:10:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 180
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains

[{"session_id":"2_MX40NTUwNDg1Mn5-MTQ1Nzk1MDIxOTVNGZmUwS1N3bFF2LzhvREZORVN-fg","partner_id":"404852","create_dt":"Mon Mar 12 03:10:19 PDT 2016","media_server_url":""}]
```

Comment: `json_decode()` Which [can be found in the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you confused by the fact HTTP headers are included in the output?

If so - **drop** this line: `curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);`

That is responsible for including the HTTP headers in the output.  (See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php )

Comment: awsome!!  Thanks  you saved my hair :P

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode function to parse it as an object or array:

```
$result = '[{"session_id":"2_MX40NTUwNDg1Mn5-MTQ1Nzk1MDIxOTVNGZmUwS1N3bFF2LzhvREZORVN-fg","partner_id":"404852","create_dt":"Mon Mar 12 03:10:19 PDT 2016","media_server_url":""}]';
echo "<pre>";
$json = json_decode($result,true);
print_r($json);// You may access print_r($json{0}->create_dt); etc
```

References:

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) - PHP Manual